# MVVM Source generator binding not working 2023 .NET7

Tags: c#, mvvm, .net-7.0

I am trying to implement a simple UI with sidebar navigation. But I am struggling to change the view on click. I looked at every course but looks like Microsoft courses do not go beyond FullName...........

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public SettingsViewModel SettingsVM;
        public ReportViewModel ReportVM;

        public object MainView => currentView;

        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MainView))]
        private object currentView;


        [RelayCommand]
        public void Settings() => currentView = SettingsVM;

        [RelayCommand]
        public void Report() => currentView = ReportVM;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ReportVM = new ReportViewModel();
            SettingsVM = new SettingsViewModel();
            currentView = ReportVM;
        }
    }
```

This is XAML

```
<ContentControl 
Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Column="1"
Margin="5,5,5,5"
Content="{Binding MainView}"/>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be some sort of "Main Layout?"  There are better ways to do this; consult the documentation of whatever technology this is to find the canonical way to do a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work but no fully using MVVM source generator.

Solution:

```
partial class NavigationVM:ObservableObject
{
    private object _currentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set { _currentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Monitoring() => CurrentView = new MonitoringVM();
    [RelayCommand]
    private void Settings() => CurrentView = new SettingsVM();
    [RelayCommand]
    private void Configuration() => CurrentView = new ConfigurationVM();
  
    public NavigationVM()
    {
        CurrentView = new MonitoringVM();
    }
}
```

I did not know how or what was the problem with using [ObservableProperty] and [NotifyChangeFor...] attributes